# isSaleable product save

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.4, stock, stock-status

Use Case

From a product with quantity 0 and Out of stock status.

I have an event

```
<event name="catalog_product_save_after">
    <observer name="stock_alert" instance="Cpy\StockAlert\Observer\SaveProduct" />
</event>
```

Change the value adding quantity and setting in stock status

When I check the product saleable value in the observer

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    var_dump($product->isSaleable());
```

False is printed.

If I save a second time

Then true is printed.

Conclusion, I guess my observer runs before the value is really updated...I can't understand why though as it's supposed to be after the product save ?
So I guess an other observer is acting there but...I can't tell which one, why and how to fix this.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

When do you need to retrieve stock status update? Only after modification from dashboar/through API or also when product is sold/returned by customer (on order cancel)?

Take a look at module Magento_InventoryProductAlert which uses a plugin to retrieve product stock info from MSI: (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/inventory/index.html)